# How do market participants know intentions of other players

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure

I'm reading a paper on order anticipation strategy and came across this line in the paper:

> We assume that all model parameters, including `n` and `∆ := (∆0 , . . .
>   , ∆n )`, are known to all strategic traders. Hence all traders
>   anticipate the net orders of all other traders.

I have read similar arguments made in some other papers as well. I wonder if it is fair to make such an assumption. I havent read the entire paper because this line left me puzzled. Can someone please share some insights on this points.

Link to the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.00599.pdf)

---EDIT----
In the above comment. n is the number of strategic participants and ∆i is the number of shares that the ith participants want to buy/sell.

Comment: Of course it is ridiculous to assume that " all traders anticipate the net orders of all other traders." Anybody who trades in markets knows that this is nonsense...
That is why all this game-theory literature on optimal trading is useless.
I do not know of a single algo-trading shop which applies any of this.

Comment: I have to disagree with @GeekBoy, I consider game-theory applied to optimal trading as a way to study the robustness of algos: what would be needed to be changed if other participants act in a detrimental way (ie if they have information about your flow)? Of course you cannot apply directly these results, but do you know if it is better to protect your also by accelerating your trading speed a multiplicative or an additive way? this literature gives you answers.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you may have a look at two other papers

- [Mean-Field Game Strategies for Optimal Execution](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2578733) by Huang, Jaimungal and Nourian.
- [Mean Field Game of Controls and An Application To Trade Crowding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09904) by Cardaliaguet and L

In the second one, we explain how on the long run, market participants try to anticipate price pressure. For instance intermediaries (ie investment banks and brokers) often publish analysis on the "current trends" in term of flows.

Moreover, on the short term, you can have a look at this other paper

- [Limit Order Strategic Placement with Adverse Selection Risk and the Role of Latency](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00261) by Mounjid and L.

We give in it the example of the predictive power of the liquidity imbalance. This "signal" is often used in intraday. At my knowledge, it has been popularized by [Trade arrival dynamics and quote imbalance in a limit order book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0514).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Lehalle. I'm reading through the papers you've mentioned